# Бот ВК на питоне, как отправлять фотку с пк, а не вк?

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот

Создаю бота ВК, хочу чтобы при событии ' новое сообщение' ( определенное сообщение)
помимо текста, он также отправлял фотку с пк, что и куда добавить нужно?)

Comment: Код покажите свой.

Comment: Во-первых, какой модуль вы используете? Во-вторых, покажите, пожалуйста, свой код. Таким образом отвечающие быстро смогут подредактировать его и не придётся им писать свою версию кода. Иначе, ответа можно и 3 года ждать